# Android Studio попадают логи в Logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, macos

После обновления Android Studio (AS) до последней стабильной версии (4.0) постоянно пропадают логи в Logcat. Примерно через 10-15 минут они исчезают для всех устройств-эмуляторов и больше не отображаются. С прошлой версией AS проблем не было и все работало хорошо

Что пробовал и не получил никакого результата:
 - закрыть-открыть AS
 - удалить приложение с устройства
 - clean 
 - rebuild
 - invalidate and restart (в 1 из 5 случаев работает)

Сейчас по постоянной основе работает только перезапуск всего ПК, но это вообще не вариант.
Сталкивался ли кто-то с подобным и как решили эту проблему?

Система: macOS 10.13.6

Comment: попробуйте отключить фильтрацию логов для вашего приложения, чтобы логи шли со всей системы в целом, а потом снова включите логи для вашего приложения

Comment: так а зачем сюда писать, пишите в тех поддержку